# Finding SE of Slope from SE of Estimate

Tags: regression, standard-error

I'm having issues finding the SE of the Slope to use for a T-test in a monte carlo simulation to test whether my coefficient (beta) is significantly different from 1. The problem is my intercept is fixed for 0.

I know the formula is
SE of Estimate / SSX = SE of Slope

This seems to hold as long as there is an intercept.
Using LINEST function in Excel I can confirm that SE of Estimate / SSX = SE of Slope is true when there is an intercept, but as soon as I don't have an intercept I can no longer replicate the results from LINEST.

I have linked an imagine from Excel to clarify if it isn't clear:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpCMp.jpg

What is the issue?